# Is there a way to embed hidden information in a paragraph in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

This might seem a strange question, but I want to know if there's any way of storing additional (and invisible) text in a Word document in the same way that you might store data in an html document as an attribute or using the $().data() method in JQuery.

My aim is to allow me to write a document that contains my lecture notes, with headings and subheadings, but that also stores *questions* so I can test myself on that section of the document. I want to be able to later take the questions and the text that answers that question out using Word Interop (programatically).

Since I'm not going to be doing this manually, it doesn't have to be easy, but I'd like to know if this is possible, or if I should start writing my notes in HTML.

Comment: You could potentially store it with a zero point font, or edit the document by hand (it is basically a zipped folder; this however is not recommended)

another option is to use a clear/same bg/fg color and just have blank space

Comment: Can't you use the commenting functionnality ?

Comment: You can mark text as hidden. Then you have to remember not to "Show Hidden Text" when you are testing yourself.

You could use Endnotes.

There are other ways, but those are probably the simplest and do not involve programming.

Comment: @bibadia +1 That is a fantastic suggestion, thank you! (even if I ended up using comments). For anyone who sees this later, you can set text to hidden by Selecting the text -> Right Clicking -> Font -> Tick Hidden

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [edi9999](https://superuser.com/users/196505/edi9999)'s suggestion of using comments to store the questions, because this lets me hide comments and view the document as a summary, and then turn them back on to test myself.

You can also easily get the comments [programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.comments.aspx), which fit all my criteria.